# How to dynamically override forms and/or views using Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working on a web application using Zend that we'd like to ship with some default forms and views. We'd like the client to be able to create custom forms and/or views that could be placed in another directory that could override the default forms. IE, Zend would check to see if any custom forms (or views) existed, and if so, load those, otherwise load the default ones.

Is this possible to do using Zend?

I already thought about creating subclasses for every form that by default would just call the parent constructor, but that seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: When your client create a new form, will the fields  be stored in a database?

Comment: I think we're going to limit them to fields that already exist in the db, and given the non technical nature of the clients, it's most likely that we'll actually be creating the forms for them.

It would be nice to have the forms separated like this for upgrading. If we have separate default forms from custom ones, we can ensure that the default ones are always up to date and functional to fall back on.

Comment: And through what the client will change the form? In an admin area? IE "Select the form you'll want in the list bellow:" ?

Comment: Well, the client will probably come to us and ask us to change the form (it's the way our clients seem to do things).

Comment: Hum... Why you do not just create the forms with different names and then when your client ask for it you change it in your controller? or even in your application.ini if you'd need something more ease? You can create forms.ini for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a factory/service class, configured with your custom and default prefixes/paths, whose job is to instantiate the requested form. It would be the job of this factory class to check first for the presence of a custom form and to fallback to the default form.

So you could have default forms named something like `My_Form_Default_User` appearing in `application/forms/default` and your default forms named something like `My_Form_Custom_User` appearing in `application/forms/custom`. Then client code could call something like `My_FormFactory::createForm('user')`.

An alternative might be to name the forms the same thing (Ex: `My_Form_User`) for both cases, but then configure the autoloader with paths to both locations. If the autoloader finds the custom form, cool. If not, it falls back to the default location. But that approach seems a bit dicier to me.

Comment: I think the factory ideia is great, with some kind of name convention, the user can simply put the form in the directory and the factory class will load than.

Comment: I wanted to use the autoloader like you describe, but it's a pretty complex beast and I couldn't figure out how to load resources before the default zend stuff. I think I'll make a separate question for that. edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373891/how-to-configure-the-zend-autoloader-to-load-a-custom-path-for-resources-before-t

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Have a section in your application.ini which will be read before rendering the view. The default setting would indicate to your controller that it must load YOUR form but if the client wants to load their own form for a given view then they can simply delete the corresponding entry from your application.ini (you might well have to provide a custom application.ini which can be customized by your client but which is different from the application.ini used by your own application)