# How to configure the Zend autoloader to load a custom path for resources before the default path

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

Separate but related to [How to dynamically override forms and/or views using Zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363764/how-to-dynamically-override-forms-and-or-views-using-zend).

I want Zend to try to load custom forms/views before loading a set of default forms for a web application to let clients create custom forms for their application.

How do you configure the autoloader to load a different path before your default zend classes?

Comment: While it doesn't solve this problem, my solution was to create a second set of views and forms that extended our default views and forms, then load them all the time. Not as nice as I'd like, but it has its advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the other question, you'll need to use a factory class. This class will check in a predefined directory the existence of the new form or otherwise the default form.

All you will need to do is something like:

```
// $formname is the parameter passed to the factory class
$defaultclassname = "Default_Form_{$formname}";
$classname = "New_Form_{$formname}";
if(file_exists("/path/to/directory/of/new/{$formname}.php"))
    return new $classname();
else
    return new $defaultclassname();
```

This will be done in your factory class, something like /MyLib/Form/Form_Factory.php

And then, in your controller:

```
$form = MyLib_Form_Factory::createForm('user');
```

Comment: I'm still not convinced that a factory class is necessary. Zend_Loader::loadClass takes a second parameter for directories to search, in the given order, but I can't find any way to pass that information to the autoloader.